# udacity sunshine- app crashes on mobile even after I connect to the internet using AsyncTask

Tags: java, android

These are the logcats i am getting after I run the application on my mobile

```
02-24 23:40:03.153: E/AndroidRuntime(32501): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-24 23:40:03.153: E/AndroidRuntime(32501): Process: sunshine.com.example.himanshu.sunshine, PID: 32501
02-24 23:40:03.153: E/AndroidRuntime(32501): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
02-24 23:40:03.153: E/AndroidRuntime(32501):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
02-24 23:40:03.153: E/AndroidRuntime(32501):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
02-24 23:40:03.153: E/AndroidRuntime(32501):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:137)
02-24 23:40:03.153: E/AndroidRuntime(32501):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
02-24 23:40:03.153: E/AndroidRuntime(32501):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
02-24 23:40:03.153: E/AndroidRuntime(32501):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:456)
02-24 23:40:03.153: E/AndroidRuntime(32501):    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:882)
02-24 23:40:03.153: E/AndroidRuntime(32501):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:139)
02-24 23:40:03.153: E/AndroidRuntime(32501):    at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:148)
02-24 23:40:03.153: E/AndroidRuntime(32501):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:276)
02-24 23:40:03.153: E/AndroidRuntime(32501):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
02-24 23:40:03.153: E/AndroidRuntime(32501):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:373)
02-24 23:40:03.153: E/AndroidRuntime(32501):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:106)
02-24 23:40:03.153: E/AndroidRuntime(32501):    at sunshine.com.example.himanshu.sunshine.MainActivity$ForecastFragment$FetchWeatherTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:139)
02-24 23:40:03.153: E/AndroidRuntime(32501):    at sunshine.com.example.himanshu.sunshine.MainActivity$ForecastFragment.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:92)
02-24 23:40:03.153: E/AndroidRuntime(32501):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performOptionsItemSelected(Fragment.java:1894)
02-24 23:40:03.153: E/AndroidRuntime(32501):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchOptionsItemSelected(FragmentManager.java:2034)
02-24 23:40:03.153: E/AndroidRuntime(32501):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:356)
02-24 23:40:03.153: E/AndroidRuntime(32501):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onMenuItemSelected(ActionBarActivity.java:155)
02-24 23:40:03.153: E/AndroidRuntime(32501):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate$1.onMenuItemSelected(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:74)
02-24 23:40:03.153: E/AndroidRuntime(32501):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.onMenuItemSelected(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:556)
02-24 23:40:03.153: E/AndroidRuntime(32501):    at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:802)
02-24 23:40:03.153: E/AndroidRuntime(32501):    at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:153)
02-24 23:40:03.153: E/AndroidRuntime(32501):    at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:949)
02-24 23:40:03.153: E/AndroidRuntime(32501):    at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:939)
02-24 23:40:03.153: E/AndroidRuntime(32501):    at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.onItemClick(MenuPopupHelper.java:187)
02-24 23:40:03.153: E/AndroidRuntime(32501):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:300)
02-24 23:40:03.153: E/AndroidRuntime(32501):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1143)
02-24 23:40:03.153: E/AndroidRuntime(32501):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3044)
02-24 23:40:03.153: E/AndroidRuntime(32501):    at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3833)
02-24 23:40:03.153: E/AndroidRuntime(32501):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
02-24 23:40:03.153: E/AndroidRuntime(32501):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-24 23:40:03.153: E/AndroidRuntime(32501):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
02-24 23:40:03.153: E/AndroidRuntime(32501):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
02-24 23:40:03.153: E/AndroidRuntime(32501):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-24 23:40:03.153: E/AndroidRuntime(32501):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-24 23:40:03.153: E/AndroidRuntime(32501):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
02-24 23:40:03.153: E/AndroidRuntime(32501):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
```

This is my MainActivity.java file:

```
    package sunshine.com.example.himanshu.sunshine;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuInflater;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.lang.reflect.Array;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.io.*;
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.container, new ForecastFragment())
                        .commit();

            }
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        /**
         * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
         */
        public static class ForecastFragment extends Fragment {

            public ForecastFragment() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setHasOptionsMenu(true);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.forecast_fragment,menu);
                super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                int id=item.getItemId();
                if(id==R.id.refresh_action)
                {
                    FetchWeatherTask fetch=new FetchWeatherTask();
                    fetch.doInBackground();
                    return true;
                }
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
                String forecastArray[] = {"Today-sunny-23/34",
                        "Tomorrow-foggy-45/67",
                        "Wed-asteroid-54/34",
                        "Thursday--sunny-34/56",
                        "Fri-foggy-45/34"
                        , "Sat-day-23/45"
                        , "Sun-Sunny-34/65", "Someday-gloomy-78/90", "Sat-day-23/45",
                        "Wed-asteroid-54/34", "Today-sunny-23/34"};
                List weekForecast = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(forecastArray));
                ArrayAdapter mForecastAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item_forecast, R.id.list_item_forecast_textview, weekForecast);
                ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
                listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);


                return rootView;
            }

            public class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask {
                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... urls) {
                    // These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
    // so that they can be closed in the finally block.
                    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
                    BufferedReader reader = null;

    // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
                    String forecastJsonStr = null;

                    try {
                        // Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
                        // Possible parameters are available at OWM's forecast API page, at
                        // http://openweathermap.org/API#forecast
                        URL url = new URL("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=94043&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7");

                        // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
                        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                        urlConnection.connect();

                        // Read the input stream into a String
                        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                        if (inputStream == null) {
                            // Nothing to do.
                            forecastJsonStr = null;
                        }
                        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                        String line;
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                            // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                            // buffer for debugging.
                            buffer.append(line + "\n");
                        }

                        if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                            // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                            forecastJsonStr = null;
                        }
                        forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error ", e);
                        // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attempting
                        // to parse it.
                        forecastJsonStr = null;
                    } finally {
                        if (urlConnection != null) {
                            urlConnection.disconnect();
                        }
                        if (reader != null) {
                            try {
                                reader.close();
                            } catch (final IOException e) {
                                Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error closing stream", e);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                return null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is my Android Manifest File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="sunshine.com.example.himanshu.sunshine" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The app crashes whenever I run it on my mobile. Please help me, and thanks if you find the solution
I have created an AsyncTask to connect to the INTERNET an am not using the main thread to connect to the Internet

Comment: Instead of calling `doInBackground()` yourself on the main thread, call `execute()` to have `doInBackground()` called on a background thread.

Comment: You may *trying* not to use the main thread to connect to the Internet, but the exception shows that you are.